# How to remove headers and footers for pages between chapters?

Tags: header-footer, chapters, double-sided, blank-page

To ensure that a new chapter starts on a right-hand page, the `book` class (and the `report` class with the options `twoside` and `openright`) will insert blank pages between chapters if necessary. However, these pages still contain the headers and footers as defined by the class. How can I remove those?

Note: I know that I can manually add `\clearpage\thispagestyle{empty}` at the appropriate points of my document. However, this seems awkward and is prone to fail if I change my document later. I'm looking for automatic solutions.

Comment: It is not enough to put `\pagestyle{empty}` where you do not want the headers, and then `\pagestyle{your-page-style}` to bring them back?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Use the [`emptypage`](http://ctan.org/pkg/emptypage) package.

Comment: I was about to ask for more information, but I realized there really isn't any necessary: Adding `\usepackage{emptypage}` removes headers and footers on empty pages. I was pleasantly surprised :)

Comment: @AchalDave Pleasantly surprised is an understatement! 

Comment: Note that this also removes the page numbers.

Comment: @Jon but page numbers still increment. Any idea how to skip avoid this? Or is it bad practice?

Comment: @JesseKnight It is a bad practice

Comment: I think you should add to the answer that it is just enough to load the package.

Comment: @CarLaTeX Thanks. I'm writing a thesis package, and the department has some odd requirements (e.g. TOC must be page "iii"). I'll try to talk them out of it...

Comment: @JesseKnight Use alphabetical numbering for the first pages before the main content is usual, don't worry :)

Answer (score 19):

You could redefine `\cleardoublepage`:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\cleardoublepage}{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else
\hbox{}%
\thispagestyle{empty}%
\newpage%
\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
\makeatother
```

The [`fancyhdr`](https://texdoc.org/pkg/fancyhdr) package deals with this topic in its documentation. Have a look at section 20 *Those blank pages* on page 26.

Comment: This is not on page 26 (section 20).

Answer (score 8):

I believe this is the default behaviour for the [`memoir`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/) class.

It can be further (bizarrely) tailored by, for example

```
\cleartooddpage[\thispagestyle{companion}]
```

or

```
\cleartoevenpage[\thispagestyle{Ruled}]
```

but, sadly, not for `\cleartorecto` or `cleartoverso`

---

Slightly more diligent research show this: `\cleartorecto` and `cleartoverso` include this call:

```
 \thispagestyle{cleared}
```

The `cleared` memoir page style is defined by:

```
\aliaspagestyle{cleared}{empty}
```

and all is nicely described in section 7.2, "Page Styles" of the memoir manual (memman.pdf)

Answer (score 5):

The `KOMA-Script` classes allow to set the pagestyle of inserted "blank" pages with the option `cleardoublepage` (which defaults to `empty`). See section 3.13 of the `KOMA-Script` manual for details.

Comment: One can also tweak the styles directly by \ofoot etc. See scrguien.pdf

Answer (score 2):

the default behaviour for the ams document classes is to omit running heads from otherwise empty pages between chapters.

Answer (score 0):

## KOMA Script

The `KOMA-Script` documentation lists in chapter **3.13** the following commands to move following content to the next right-hand page:

```
\clearpage
\cleardoublepage
\cleardoublepageusingstyle{pagestyle}
\cleardoubleemptypage
\cleardoubleplainpage
\cleardoublestandardpage
\cleardoubleoddpage
\cleardoubleoddpageusingstyle{pagestyle}
\cleardoubleoddemptypage
\cleardoubleoddplainpage
\cleardoubleoddstandardpage
\cleardoubleevenpage
\cleardoubleevenpageusingstyle{pagestyle}
\cleardoubleevenemptypage
\cleardoubleevenplainpage
\cleardoubleevenstandardpage
```

Available pagestyles can be found in chapter **3.12** of the documentation:

```
empty % don't show nothing
plain % just show page numbers
headings
myheadings
```

### Usage

So if you want your content to start on the next right-hand page without any headers or footers on the left-hand page before, you could use `\cleardoubleemptypage` like so:

```
\chapter{My Old Chapter}
   Content goes here...

\cleardoubleemptypage % insert blank left-hand page
\chapter{My New Chapter}
   Content goes here ...
```

### Source

The official documentation can be found here on [ctan.org](https://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script).