# How to force output to a left (or right) page?

Tags: page-breaking, double-sided

I am putting together a document that has several cover pages, both for front and back cover.  The bulk of the document is two-sided.  Cover pages, however, must be right-side (or left-side, for the back cover) pages.

How can I force the next page to specifically be a right-side-page or a left-side-page?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

For odd / right-side pages you can use `\cleardoublepage`  in two-sided documents. (In one-sided ones `\cleardoublepage` is identical to `\clearpage`)

To force even / left-side pages you would need to define your own macro based on `\cleardoublepage`, but with reversed logic:

```
\documentclass{book}

\newcommand*\cleartoleftpage{%
  \clearpage
  \ifodd\value{page}\hbox{}\newpage\fi
}

% Demonstration / Test:
\begin{document}
  Title on right side
\cleardoublepage
  other title on right side
\cleartoleftpage
  on the left side
\cleartoleftpage
  also on the left side
\cleardoublepage
  right side again
\end{document}
```

A more complex version which behaves nicely in single-sided documents and also supports two-column mode is:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\cleartoleftpage}{%
  \clearpage
    \if@twoside
    \ifodd\c@page
      \hbox{}\newpage
      \if@twocolumn
        \hbox{}\newpage
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
}
\makeatother
```

This is the definition of `\cleardoublepage` just with the `\else` removed to negate the logic, i.e. make it force even pages instead of odd.

Answer (score 25):

As Martin explained, `\cleardoublepage` is a standard LaTeX command to force a break to an odd (right, recto) page in double-sided documents. The [`KOMA-script`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/koma-script.html) classes and the [`memoir`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/memoir.html) class offer numerous custom commands for page-breaking:

- With KOMA-script, use `\cleardoubleevenemptypage` to force a break to an even (left, verso) page. (If necessary, this will produce an additional odd page with page style `empty`, as is the default in KOMA-script.) See section 3.13 of the `KOMA-script` manual for other available commands.
- With memoir, use `\cleartoverso` to force a break to an even page. See section 18.13 of the `memoir` manual for other available commands.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer

Thanks for the MWE. I need an output that should not  add a white-numberd-page in between the forced even/odd pages.

Could you help me out in finding this issue. Appreciate your attention. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You can modify both `\cleardoublepage` (as in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1683/131482)) and @Martin Scharrer's code to insert, if necessary, an empty page:

```
\makeatletter
\def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside
\ifodd\c@page
\else\hbox{}\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage
\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
\makeatother
```

and

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\cleartoleftpage}{%
  \clearpage
    \if@twoside
    \ifodd\c@page
      \hbox{}\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage
      \if@twocolumn
        \hbox{}\newpage
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
}
\makeatother
```