# Chapters only on even pages, sections without pagebreaks?

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking, chapters, koma-script, double-sided

I'm having a few questions about KOMA script configuration and would love if you guys could help me out:

1. How can I make all chapters only appear on even pages?
2. How can I make all sections NOT have pagebreaks after each other?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! What you describe is actually the default behaviour of the `scrbook` class. Please provide more information or -- even better -- add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: @lockstep: Chapters normally start on odd pages, don't they? I think we had such a question (I mean for point 1) already, but can't find it just now. There shouldn't be any page breaks between sections by default, so point 2 is a little confusing.

Comment: @Martin: Dang! Vany: Excuse my ignorance -- will try to come up with an answer.

Comment: Done! But we really need information with regard to point 2.

Comment: My guess regarding point 2 is a misuse of `\include`.

Answer (score 11):

Re point 1: Use the class option `open=left`.

```
\documentclass[open=left]{scrbook}

\begin{document}

\chapter{foo}

Some text.

\chapter{bar}

Some text.

\end{document}
```

Comment: I just was going to suggest to redefine `\cleardoublepage` to the macro shown in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11707/how-to-force-output-to-a-left-or-right-page/11709#11709, but this is of course much better!

Comment: @Martin: and TomBombadil did it for you ;-)