# double-page spread chapter page with chapter number

Tags: chapters, koma-script, double-sided

I'm creating a thesis which should have a double-page spread chapter page with an background image.

I'm almost there, however when using `\thechapter` is gives me the previous chapter number, wich makes sense, since the chapter is not started.

See the example below, where the chaptername is on the rightside (due to cleardoublepage setting) and my own created `\thechapter` (is 0 should be 1 of course).

rif2-links and rif2-rechts is  just an image of size: 208 × 295 pixels

So what I want is the chaptername on the left side, possible exact the same chapter number format as coming from `quotchap`.

Complete example can be downloaded here (with the images)
http://rob.lensen.nu/files/test_tex.zip

```
\documentclass[b5paper]{scrbook}
\KOMAoptions{
DIV=last,
chapterprefix=true,
titlepage=false,
twoside=semi,
fontsize= 10pt,
cleardoublepage=empty
}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{color,scrpage2,eso-pic}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype}              % Better typography
\usepackage[english]{babel}     % english Sprache
\usepackage{fixltx2e}           % Verschiedene Bugfixes fr Latex2e
\usepackage{ae,aecompl}         % Schriftarten richtig einbetten, statt ekliger Bitmaps
%\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}    % Math packages
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}                   % Enable pdflatex
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{textcomp}           % Mehr Symbole
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage[grey,utopia]{quotchap} % Fanche chapter page
\usepackage{ellipsis}           % Optimiert die Leerrume um Auslassungspunkte
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}  % Mehrere Bilder in eine figure-Umgebung
\usepackage{ifthen}             % \ifthenelse-Befehl
%\usepackage[square]{natbib}        % Schner zitieren
%\usepackage[gather]{chapterbib}
    %\usepackage[style=numeric,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{enumerate}          % \begin{enumerate}[a)] oder [I.] oder [{Bsp.} 1:] ...
%\bibliographystyle{styles/elsart-num}
%\addbibresource{References/test.bib}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\cleardoubleevenplainpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\CenterWallPaper{1}{rif2-links}
\Huge\ \thechapter \normalsize
\chapter[foo]{Foo}\label{section:_GoBack}
\vfill
\begin{flushleft}
Author name\\
\null
\vfill
\end{flushleft}
\ClearWallPaper
\CenterWallPaper{1}{rif2-rechts}
\newpage
\ClearWallPaper
\section*{Abstract}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: the question [Chapters only on even pages, ...](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27204/), mentions that `scrbook` has an option `[open=left]`.  this might be useful.

Comment: Please have a look at [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) to see how a   *minimal* working example is created. For example we do not have `styles/own_quotchap.sty` and therefore cannot know what nice things it does. "I'm creating a thesis for my sister" Nice, could you please write my thesis, too? ;-) You wanted to write: "I'm helping my sister with the formatting of her thesis", didn't you? (Her advisor might be reading you post...) ;-)

Comment: You are completely right Stephen, reworded the phrase and fixed the code so everybody can use it. Also added link to the images for a complete working document.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `\thechapter`, use `\the\numexpr\value{chapter}+1\relax`, which will add 1 to the current value of the chapter counter. Note that the reference (if you're using [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)) will still point to the page containing your actual chapter heading - the call to `\chapter`. However, since you're only printing elements/constructing the chapter "heading" this should be fine.