# Back cover for a book

Tags: covers

I have been looking for back cover LaTeX code for a while now, and I do not seem to be able to find a correct answer.

The closest I have gotten so far is this URL: http://latex-my.blogspot.ch/2010/01/front-and-back-covers.html , which I have not yet been able to compile without errors.

What I am looking for:

- A standard back code: a short summary of the book, the ISBN and some other info such as year of publication and website.
- ISBN being LaTeX generated is a good nice to have.

Also: achieve a way to force this back cover to be on the left side (thus the contrary of \cleardoublepage, which would force the page to appear on the left instead of on the right).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Regarding your second question about having the cover on certain side, [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11707/how-to-force-output-to-a-left-or-right-page) Q/A might help.