# How to use openright option in The Legrand Orange Book including TOC?

Tags: sectioning, chapters, page-numbering

I am trying to have [The Legrand Orange Book](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/the-legrand-orange-book) in openright two sided book. I tried inserting blank pages at the start of the TOC, before each chapter page, but in vain. I tried [this method](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11707/how-to-force-output-to-a-left-or-right-page) and also tried openright, openany options but still can't produce one. Any has idea please!

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,fleqn]{book}
\usepackage{geometry} 
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} 
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\setlist{nolistsep} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{243,102,25} 
\usepackage{avant}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic,citestyle=numeric,sorting=nyt,sortcites=true,autopunct=true,babel=hyphen,hyperref=true,abbreviate=false,backref=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\defbibheading{bibempty}{}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{titletoc}
%\contentsmargin{0cm} % Removes the default margin
% Part text styling
\titlecontents{part}[0cm]
{\addvspace{20pt}\centering\large\bfseries}
{}
{}
{}
% Chapter text styling
\titlecontents{chapter}[1.25cm] % Indentation
{\addvspace{12pt}\large\sffamily\bfseries} % Spacing and font options for chapters
{\color{ocre!60}\contentslabel[\Large\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}\color{ocre}} % Chapter number
{\color{ocre}}  
{\color{ocre!60}\normalsize\;\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage} % Page number
% Section text styling
\titlecontents{section}[1.25cm] % Indentation
{\addvspace{3pt}\sffamily\bfseries} % Spacing and font options for sections
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}} % Section number
{}
{\hfill\color{black}\thecontentspage} % Page number
[]
% Subsection text styling
\titlecontents{subsection}[1.25cm] % Indentation
{\addvspace{1pt}\sffamily\small} % Spacing and font options for subsections
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}} % Subsection number
{}
{\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage} % Page number
[]
% List of figures
\titlecontents{figure}[0em]
{\addvspace{-5pt}\sffamily}
{\thecontentslabel\hspace*{1em}}
{}
{\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage}
[]
% List of tables
\titlecontents{table}[0em]
{\addvspace{-5pt}\sffamily}
{\thecontentslabel\hspace*{1em}}
{}
{\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage}
[]
% Chapter text styling
\titlecontents{lchapter}[0em] % Indenting
{\addvspace{15pt}\large\sffamily\bfseries} % Spacing and font options for chapters
{\color{ocre}\contentslabel[\Large\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}\color{ocre}} % Chapter number
{}  
{\color{ocre}\normalsize\sffamily\bfseries\;\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage} % Page number
% Section text styling
\titlecontents{lsection}[0em] % Indenting
{\sffamily\small} % Spacing and font options for sections
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}} % Section number
{}
{}
% Subsection text styling
\titlecontents{lsubsection}[.5em] % Indentation
{\normalfont\footnotesize\sffamily} % Font settings
{}
{}
{}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Required for header and footer configuration
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\sffamily\normalsize\bfseries\chaptername\ \thechapter.\ #1}{}} % Chapter text font settings
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\sffamily\normalsize\thesection\hspace{5pt}#1}{}} % Section text font     settings
\fancyhf{} \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\sffamily\normalsize\thepage} % Font setting for the page number in the header
\fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark} % Print the nearest section name on the left side of odd pages
\fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark} % Print the current chapter name on the right side of even pages
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt} % Width of the rule under the header
\addtolength{\headheight}{2.5pt} % Increase the spacing around the header slightly
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} % Removes the rule in the footer
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhead{}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}} % Style for when a plain pagestyle is specified
% Removes the header from odd empty pages at the end of chapters
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{
\clearpage\ifodd\c@page\else
\hbox{}
\vspace*{\fill}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\fi}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm} % For math equations, theorems, symbols, etc
\newcommand{\intoo}[2]{\mathopen{]}#1\,;#2\mathclose{[}}
\newcommand{\ud}{\mathop{\mathrm{{}d}}\mathopen{}}
\newcommand{\intff}[2]{\mathopen{[}#1\,;#2\mathclose{]}}
\newtheorem{notation}{Notation}[chapter]
 % numbered part in the table of contents
\newcommand{\@mypartnumtocformat}[2]{%
\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
\noindent\colorbox{ocre!20}{\strut\parbox[c][.7cm]{\ecart}{\color{ocre!70}\Large\sffamily\bfseries\centering#1}}\hskip\esp    \colorbox{ocre!40}{\strut\parbox[c][.7cm]{\linewidth-\ecart-\esp}{\Large\sffamily\centering#2}}}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% unnumbered part in the table of contents
\newcommand{\@myparttocformat}[1]{%
\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
\noindent\colorbox{ocre!40}{\strut\parbox[c][.7cm]{\linewidth}{\Large\sffamily\centering#1}}}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newlength\esp
\setlength\esp{4pt}
\newlength\ecart
\setlength\ecart{1.2cm-\esp}
\newcommand{\thepartimage}{}%
\newcommand{\partimage}[1]{\renewcommand{\thepartimage}{#1}}%
\def\@part[#1]#2{%
\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax%
\refstepcounter{part}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\texorpdfstring{\protect\@mypartnumtocformat{\thepart}{#1}}{\partname~\thepart\ ---\ #1}}
\else%
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\texorpdfstring{\protect\@myparttocformat{#1}}{#1}}%
\fi%
\startcontents%
\markboth{}{}%
{\thispagestyle{empty}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
\node at (current page.north west){\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%   
\fill[ocre!20](0cm,0cm) rectangle (\paperwidth,-\paperheight);
\node[anchor=north] at (4cm,-3.25cm){\color{ocre!40}\fontsize{220}{100}\sffamily\bfseries\@Roman\c@part}; 
\node[anchor=south east] at (\paperwidth-1cm,-\paperheight+1cm){\parbox[t][][t]{8.5cm}{
\printcontents{l}{0}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}%
}};
\node[anchor=north east] at (\paperwidth-1.5cm,-3.25cm){\parbox[t][][t]{15cm}{\strut\raggedleft\color{white}\fontsize{30}    {30}\sffamily\bfseries#2}};
\end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\@endpart}
\def\@spart#1{%
\startcontents%
\phantomsection
{\thispagestyle{empty}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
\node at (current page.north west){\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%   
\fill[ocre!20](0cm,0cm) rectangle (\paperwidth,-\paperheight);
\node[anchor=north east] at (\paperwidth-1.5cm,-3.25cm){\parbox[t][][t]{15cm}{\strut\raggedleft\color{white}\fontsize{30}    {30}\sffamily\bfseries#1}};
\end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\texorpdfstring{%
\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
\noindent\protect\colorbox{ocre!40}{\strut\protect\parbox[c][.7cm]{\linewidth}{\Large\sffamily\protect\centering #1\quad    \mbox{}}}}{#1}}%
\@endpart}
\def\@endpart{\vfil\newpage
\if@twoside
\if@openright
\null
\thispagestyle{empty}%
\newpage
\fi
\fi
\if@tempswa
\twocolumn
\fi}
% A switch to conditionally include a picture, implemented by  Christian Hupfer
\newif\ifusechapterimage
\usechapterimagetrue
\newcommand{\thechapterimage}{}%
\newcommand{\chapterimage}[1]{\ifusechapterimage\renewcommand{\thechapterimage}{#1}\fi}%
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
{\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
\if@mainmatter
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node at (current page.north west)
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\ifusechapterimage\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]    {\thechapterimage}\fi};
\draw[anchor=west] (\Gm@lmargin,-9cm) node [line width=2pt,rounded corners=15pt,draw=ocre,fill=white,fill     opacity=0.5,inner sep=15pt]{\strut\makebox[22cm]{}};
\draw[anchor=west] (\Gm@lmargin+.3cm,-9cm) node {\huge\sffamily\bfseries\color{black}\thechapter. #1\strut};
\end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\else
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node at (current page.north west)
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\ifusechapterimage\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]    {\thechapterimage}\fi};
\draw[anchor=west] (\Gm@lmargin,-9cm) node [line width=2pt,rounded corners=15pt,draw=ocre,fill=white,fill     opacity=0.5,inner sep=15pt]{\strut\makebox[22cm]{}};
\draw[anchor=west] (\Gm@lmargin+.3cm,-9cm) node {\huge\sffamily\bfseries\color{black}#1\strut};
\end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\fi\fi\par\vspace*{270\p@}}}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node at (current page.north west)
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\ifusechapterimage\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]    {\thechapterimage}\fi};
\draw[anchor=west] (\Gm@lmargin,-9cm) node [line width=2pt,rounded corners=15pt,draw=ocre,fill=white,fill     opacity=0.5,inner sep=15pt]{\strut\makebox[22cm]{}};
\draw[anchor=west] (\Gm@lmargin+.3cm,-9cm) node {\huge\sffamily\bfseries\color{black}#1\strut};
\end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\par\vspace*{270\p@}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hidelinks,backref=true,pagebackref=true,hyperindex=true,colorlinks=false,breaklinks=true,urlcolor=     ocre,bookmarks=true,bookmarksopen=false,pdftitle={Title},pdfauthor={Author}}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\bookmarksetup{
open,
numbered,
addtohook={%
\ifnum\bookmarkget{level}=0 % chapter
\bookmarksetup{bold}%
\fi
\ifnum\bookmarkget{level}=-1 % part
\bookmarksetup{color=ocre,bold}%
\fi
}
}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\coordinate [below=12cm] (midpoint) at (current page.north);
\node at (current page.north west)
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{background}}; % Background image
\draw[anchor=north] (midpoint) node [fill=ocre!30!white,fill opacity=0.6,text opacity=1,inner sep=1cm]{\Huge\centering    \bfseries\sffamily\parbox[c][][t]{\paperwidth}{\centering The Search for a Title\\[15pt] % Book title
{\Large A Profound Subtitle}\\[20pt] % Subtitle
{\huge Dr. John Smith}}}; % Author name
\end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\vfill
\endgroup
\newpage
~\vfill
\thispagestyle{empty}

\noindent Copyright \copyright\ 2013 John Smith\\ % Copyright notice

\noindent \textsc{Published by Publisher}\\ % Publisher

\noindent \textsc{book-website.com}\\ % URL

\noindent Licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial 3.0 Unported License (the ``License''). You may not use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at \url{http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/3.0}. Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the License is distributed on an \textsc{``as is'' basis, without warranties or conditions of any kind}, either express or implied. See the License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations under the License.\\ % License information

\noindent \textit{First printing, March 2013} % Printing/edition date
\chapterimage{images/nehuadmin.jpg} % Table of contents heading image
\pagestyle{empty} % No headers
%\cleardoublepage % Forces the first chapter to start on an odd page so it's on the right
%\cleartoleftpage % Forces the first chapter to start on an odd page so it's on the right
\tableofcontents % Print the table of contents itself
%\pdfbookmark{Title}{Title}
\pagestyle{fancy} % Print headers again
%\setcounter{page}{1} \pagenumbering{roman}
\part{Part One}
%\csname @openrightfalse\endcsname % force to even
\chapterimage{images/chapter_head_2.pdf} % Chapter heading image
\pagestyle{empty} % No headers
%\cleardoublepage % Forces the first chapter to start on an odd page so it's on the right
%\cleartoleftpage % Forces the first chapter to start on an odd page so it's on the right
\chapter{Text Chapter}

\section{Paragraphs of Text}\index{Paragraphs of Text}

\lipsum[1-7] % Dummy text

\section{Citation}\index{Citation}

This statement requires citation \cite{book_key}; this one is more specific \cite[122]{article_key}.

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Lists}\index{Lists}

Lists are useful to present information in a concise and/or ordered way\footnote{Footnote example...}.

\subsection{Numbered List}\index{Lists!Numbered List}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item The first item
    \item The second item
    \item The third item
\end{enumerate}

\subsection{Bullet Points}\index{Lists!Bullet Points}

\begin{itemize}
    \item The first item
    \item The second item
    \item The third item
\end{itemize}

\subsection{Descriptions and Definitions}\index{Lists!Descriptions and Definitions}

\begin{description}
    \item[Name] Description
    \item[Word] Definition
    \item[Comment] Elaboration
\end{description}

\chapter{In-text Elements}

\section{Theorems}\index{Theorems}

This is an example of theorems.

\subsection{Several equations}\index{Theorems!Several Equations}
This is a theorem consisting of several equations.
\section{Remarks}\index{Remarks}
This is an example of a remark.

\section{Corollaries}\index{Corollaries}

This is an example of a corollary.

\section{Propositions}\index{Propositions}

This is an example of propositions.

\subsection{Several equations}\index{Propositions!Several Equations}

\subsection{Single Line}\index{Propositions!Single Line}

\section{Examples}\index{Examples}

This is an example of examples.

\subsection{Equation and Text}\index{Examples!Equation and Text}

\subsection{Paragraph of Text}\index{Examples!Paragraph of Text}

\section{Exercises}\index{Exercises}

This is an example of an exercise.

\section{Problems}\index{Problems}

\section{Vocabulary}\index{Vocabulary}

Define a word to improve a students' vocabulary.

\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.75cm}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textcolor{ocre}{Index}}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: What on earth is "The Legrand Orange Book"? Sounds rather non-standard, which means in addition to the [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or see [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)) that is normally required (and would be helpful here), we'll probably also need the `.cls` or `.sty` itself or a link to it.

Comment: Sorry, I have updated my question with the source!

Comment: OK, great. But we also need *your* minimal(!) code.

Comment: Give me few minutes so that I can club everything in a single tex file.

Comment: Yes, I am simplifying it now to few pages only to include TOC and at least one chapter!

Comment: No problem! But also consider using `\usepackage{lipsum}` and the command `\lipsum[1-10]` to generate a few pages of 'dummy' (i.e., fake) text.

Comment: Adding option `openany` works in this example: with that option, chapter 1 opens on page 6 (even or verso) and chapter 2 on page 9 (odd or recto); without it, chapter 1 opens on page 7 and chapter 2 on page 11.

Comment: Yes, thanks for helping me out but I would like to have TOC, every chapter title page including index page.

Comment: I would like to have TOC, every chapter title page including index page FORCED to display like as if they are on even page whether these pages fall on EVEN or ODD.

Comment: [Crosspost](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=93738#p93738)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution (I don't make care for options `twocolumn` and `oneside`)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\chapter{\clearpage
                    \ifodd\c@page\null\thispagestyle{empty}% or plain
                    \newpage\fi
                    \thispagestyle{plain}%
                    \global\@topnum\z@
                    \@afterindentfalse
                    \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Foo}
\lipsum[1-4]
\chapter{Foo}
\lipsum[1-8]
\end{document}
```

**Update** this is for others question in comments below

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\let\oldchapter\chapter  % save original definition
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\chapter{\clearpage
                    \ifodd\c@page\null\thispagestyle{empty}% or plain
                    \addtocounter{page}{-1}%
                    \newpage\fi
                    \thispagestyle{plain}%
                    \global\@topnum\z@
                    \@afterindentfalse
                    \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
\def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else
    \hbox{}%
    \thispagestyle{empty}% or plain
    \addtocounter{page}{-1}%
    \newpage\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\lipsum[1-4]
\chapter{Foo}
\let\chapter\oldchapter  % back to the original 
\lipsum[1-9]
\chapter{Foo}
\lipsum[1-8]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am just wondering what to modify in the above code if I want to have only the first pages of TOC and Chapter 1 to start at EVEN PAGE NUMBERING [right hand side] while other first pages of remaining chapters can open at any page numbering?

Comment: Another thing I found is that this technique doesn't push down the page number. I would like to know if we can skip page numbering for each blank page.

Comment: this was not clear in your original question. Do you want to do this for all empty pages before chapters or just for tableof contents and the first. I update my answer now all clear page before chapters are not counted.

Comment: @Khaaba Please load package `showframe`. What you are doing is crazy. You are messing with basic laws of the universe, for example: right hand pages are always odd numbered.

Comment: I wanted to look for options to do the binding on page margin side or otherwise. Looking for all options in fact. Thanks I got it now including its (forced) modifications.