# In-text title (and titlepage) on left side in double-sided document

Tags: double-sided

I'm trying to make a double-sided document begin on the left side. Per default the in-text title/titlepage is always moved to the right side.

Could the titles be redefined in a double-sided document and be placed on the left side?

For the article and report classes [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11709/172164) (declaring a command `\cleartoleftpage`) *sort of* works with the drawback of inserting an empty page before the title, which isn't optimal in the beginning of the document.

Summing up what I've tried so far:

With this preamble

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article} %also trying with: report, book
\makeatletter
%From Martin Scharrer♦'s answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11709/172164
\newcommand*{\cleartoleftpage}{%
    \clearpage
    \if@twoside
    \ifodd\c@page
    \hbox{}\newpage
    \if@twocolumn
    \hbox{}\newpage
    \fi
    \fi
    \fi
}
\makeatother
\title{Title}

\begin{document}
\cleartoleftpage
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

I tried using `\cleartoleftpage` before `\maketitle` with following documentclasses and results:

- article: inserts empty page, title on the left (sort of works, with undesirabe empty page)
- report: inserts empty page, title on the left (sort of works, with undesirabe empty page)
- book: inserts two empty pages, title on the right (doesn't work at all)

So clearly this doesn't work, even in the cases where the title appears on the left side there is an unsatisfying empty page in the beginning of the document.

Answer (score 2):

The `titlepage` environment sets the page number to 1, you need to remove this setting.

```latex
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox} % for \patchcmd

\usepackage{showframe,lipsum} % for debugging

\makeatletter
% remove the page number setting
\patchcmd{\titlepage}{\setcounter {page}\@ne}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\title{Title}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}\mbox{}

\begin{titlepage}
\maketitle
\end{titlepage}

\lipsum[1-30]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Would there be a transferable solution from this to in-page titles? Since those don't reset the page number as far as I know this solution wouldn't work.

Comment: @TivV The code you have in your question prints the title on page 2.

Comment: I see, thank you. I now think that my original question was too broad, because this solution does work with the `article` and `report` classes, but not with `book` and the KOMA Script ones. Should I edit it to be specifically about article and report or leave it open for a while and see if someone knows how to solve the other ones as well?

Comment: @TivV I can't answer to what you don't ask for. You wanted `article` and only incidentally mentioned KOMA.

Comment: I noticed this sort of difficult problem and if someone knows the solution it would be good to have it on this site. That is why I asked the question using some of the most-used documentclasses: "I've tried [...] following documentclasses [... and then six different documentclasses]". I wasn't sure if there is a blanket solution to all of those problems, and I am still not, hence my question in the previous comment where I didn't ask you to solve anything, I asked you if I should narrow the scope of the original question (trusting you know better than me what makes a good question on tex.sx).

Comment: @TivV KOMA classes are sort of different from the standard ones: if you want to use them, fine, but be specific when you ask, because they require different methods to be tamed.

Comment: True. I removed all mention of KOMA from the question (might ask separately in the future).