# Left-sided table without disrupting flow of text

Tags: longtable, books, double-sided

In my thesis (`book` class) I have a long table that spans two pages. I would like the table to span both an even and odd (left and right) page for clarity.

In the answer given here (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11709), the `\cleardoublepage` command is modified to provide the same functionality but forcing content to start on an even page. While this achieves the correct positioning of the table, it forces a blank page between the end of the text and the start of the table.

I would like to force the table to start on an even page, while not disrupting the flow of text that precedes it. I've compiled a MWE, that has the following output:

[image]

The table starts on page 4 (which is desired) however page 3 is mostly blank. I would like the text after the table (page 5) to be able to continue from page 3.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage[bindingoffset=19mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum} % dummy text only

% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11709
\newcommand*\cleartoleftpage{%
  \clearpage
  \ifodd\value{page}\hbox{}\newpage\fi
}

\begin{document}

    \chapter{A}
    \lipsum
    
    % a long table over multiple pages
    \cleartoleftpage
    \begin{longtable}{ll}
        \caption{Caption}\\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
    \end{longtable}
    
    \lipsum
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: given that you may spend some months or years writing the thesis, it's probably worth spending a few minutes just moving the table in the source so that it falls at a good point with text filling the previous page. Sorry `longtable` doesn't float (and suggestions to make it float a bit using `afterpage`  are inherently fragile and I wouldn't use them on my thesis, and I wrote both those packages...)

Comment: I see. If that's the best solution then that's OK - I was only curious if there was a more automatic solution. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: The (relatively) new package `hvfloat` provides facilities that exceed the usual float options.  This might be there (I haven't checked) so it might be worth looking at the documentation.  (@DavidCarlisle's suggestion, however, is tried and true, for many years.)

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses `\afterpage` (even if it is fragile). Note that the caption number is not assigned until the page it appears on.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage[bindingoffset=19mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{lipsum} % dummy text only

\newcommand{\waitforit}[1]{% #1 = contents
  \ifodd\value{page}\afterpage{#1}%
  \else #1
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

    \chapter{A}
    \lipsum[1]
    
    % a long table over multiple pages
    \afterpage{\waitforit{\begin{longtable}{ll}
        \caption{Caption}\\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
    \end{longtable}}}
    
    \lipsum[2-16]
    
\end{document}
```