# Avoiding page numbers in empty pages?

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, blank-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove head- and footlines for pages between chapters?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1681/how-to-remove-head-and-footlines-for-pages-between-chapters)

I have empty pages in my document, many created using `\cleardoublepage`. I want the page number not to appear in them (but I do want to include them in the count). How can I do it?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The easiest way is

```
\usepackage{emptypage}
```

that will empty all blank pages created by `\cleardoublepage`.

For people using the KOMA-Script, `cleardoublepage=empty` as documentclass option might be better. For example:

```
\documentclass[…,cleardoublepage=empty,…]{scrreprt}
```