# Blank pages header

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, chapters, double-sided, blank-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove head- and footlines for pages between chapters?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1681/how-to-remove-head-and-footlines-for-pages-between-chapters)

I have a problem that I'm not able to solve with LaTeX: 
I'm in book mode. Then LaTeX leaves a blank page just after the table of contents to start the first chapter on an odd page. Before it I have configured LaTeX with `fancyhdr` to make my own header and my own footer (which contains the page numbers).

I want to leave this page without any header, how can I do that ?  Thank you !

Answer (score 5):

With

```
\usepackage{emptypage}
```

all pages with no text (generated in order to have chapters start on odd numbered pages) will be completely empty.

Comment: For me important was to set \thispagestyle{empty} in addition as mentoined above

Answer (score 2):

Also

```
\thispagestyle{empty}
```

can be used for a single page (maybe in combination with \pagebreak), but because the length of the table of contents might change (and therefore the last page of the table might have an even number), here

```
\usepackage{emptypage}
```

from the first answer is probably better. (Except when you want other empty pages to have foooter and header, of course.)