# How to change the pagestyle and print a note with \cleardoublepage?

Tags: header-footer, backgrounds

I'm using this solution provided [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30781/cleaning-bottom-of-blank-pages/33100#33100) to clear the pagestyle when blank pages are introduced due to the usage of the `openright` option in the `report` class and the `\cleardoublepage` command:

```
\let\origdoublepage\cleardoublepage
\newcommand{\clearemptydoublepage}{\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\origdoublepage}}
\let\cleardoublepage\clearemptydoublepage
```

However, besides clearing the pagestyle, I'd like to display a note in the middle of the page. I've tried with [`eso-pic`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic) and `tikz` (to get it centered, taking the left and right margins into account):

```
\let\origdoublepage\cleardoublepage
\newcommand{\clearemptydoublepage}{
\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{
 \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\correct}{((\rmargin-\lmargin)/(2*28.453)}
  \node[font=\normalfont] at ($(current page.center)+(\correct,0)$) {\blanknote};
 \end{tikzpicture}
}
\origdoublepage}}
\let\cleardoublepage\clearemptydoublepage
```

Since `\AddToShipoutPictureBG*` gets executed before `\origdoublepage`, which is in fact `\cleardoublepage`, the note is added to the blank page, if inserted, or to the first page of the next chapter. I'd like to avoid the latter behaviour, i.e. not to execute `\AddToShipoutPictureBG*` if `\origdoublepage` does nothing.

I'm using [`eso-pic`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic) instead of [`background`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/background) because `\NoBgThispage` is not working at the moment, and I use it to create other backgrounds, as exposed in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202462/how-to-clear-the-background-of-just-the-current-page) question. But I'm open to other approaches.

MWE (the incorrect behaviour is shown in page 5):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,titlepage,11pt,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\def\lmargin{3.5cm}
\def\rmargin{1.5cm}
\def\blanknote{This page intentionally left blank}
\usepackage[left=\lmargin, right=\rmargin]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}

\let\origdoublepage\cleardoublepage
\newcommand{\clearemptydoublepage}{
\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{
 \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\correct}{((\rmargin-\lmargin)/(2*28.453)}
  \node[font=\normalfont] at ($(current page.center)+(\correct,0)$) {\blanknote};
 \end{tikzpicture}
}
\origdoublepage}}
\let\cleardoublepage\clearemptydoublepage

\begin{document}
Introduction text...
\chapter{First}  \lipsum[1-9]
\chapter{Second} \lipsum[10-12]
\chapter{Third}  \lipsum[15]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: [Modify style of \cleardoublepage](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/161386)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're making it a lot more complicated than needed, `\cleardoublepage` is already generating the page: you just need to add text, no need for hooking into the output routine shipout.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,titlepage,11pt,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\def\lmargin{3.5cm}
\def\rmargin{1.5cm}
\def\blanknote{This page intentionally left blank}
\usepackage[left=\lmargin, right=\rmargin]{geometry}

\makeatletter
\def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else
 \thispagestyle{empty}%
 \hbox{}\vfill\centerline\blanknote\vfill\hbox{}\newpage
\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Introduction text...
\chapter{First}  \lipsum[1-9]
\chapter{Second} \lipsum[10-12]
\chapter{Third}  \lipsum[15]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Certainly an straight forward solution... Thank you for providing it! It works perfect for single line notes. However, it ignores `\par` commands in the `\blanknote`. How should I avoid it? I tried with `\hbox{}\vfill\centerline\mbox{\blanknote}\vfill\hbox{}` but it is not centered.

Comment: @U.Martinez-Corralchange `\centerline\blanknote` to `\begin{center}\blanknote\end{center)` (which is better latex anyway;-)