# blank pages and fancyhdr package

Tags: header-footer, blank-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove headers and footers for pages between chapters?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1681/how-to-remove-headers-and-footers-for-pages-between-chapters)

I have a document class set as book and added the `\usepackage{fancyhdr}` package. but now I have some blank pages that have the top line (the one of the heading). how can i remove only these that are the only thing (except from the page number) present on blank pages?

Comment: Should those pages (presumably before a new `\chapter`) really be blank, or should the page number be retained and only the header rule be removed?

Comment: Have you read "Multiple header style with fancyhdr" (or similarly-named) section in the manual? Would that be helpful?

Comment: @lockstep: yes, those blank pages appear before a new \chapter, i want to remove the header rule only on these pages since, in my opinion, it looks bad

Comment: Again, do you *also* want to remove the page number? And are there any chapter/section names in the header? You should provide a minimal working example.

Comment: if it is possible it would be good to remove also the the number. no, for the moment there is nothing but i think there will be some informations above that line.

i tried to post an image but since i just registered the forum won't let me do it

Comment: Removing the page number makes it easier, actually. Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1681/how-to-remove-headers-and-footers-for-pages-between-chapters -- if the answers are helpful, we can close this question as a duplicate.

Comment: I'd remove everything: `\usepackage{emptypage}`.