# delete page number in cleardoublepage

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, abstract, blank-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove headers and footers for pages between chapters?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1681/how-to-remove-headers-and-footers-for-pages-between-chapters)

I created a document using

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside, openright]{book}

\newenvironment{abstract}
    {\cleardoublepage\null\vfill\begin{center}
    \bfseries\abstractname\end{center}}
    {\vfill\null}
```

When I create

```
\begin{abstract}

\end{abstract}
```

on the page before the abstract it creates a blank page but shows the page number. I would like to delete that number. How can I do?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1681/how-to-remove-headers-and-footers-for-pages-between-chapters