# getting two pages using tableofcontents

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove headers and footers for pages between chapters?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1681/how-to-remove-headers-and-footers-for-pages-between-chapters)

I use in my document

```
\tableofcontents
```

but I got two pages.In the first I have the table of contents and the second page is empty and have only the head where it is written CONTENTS. is it standard?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian,english]{babel}

\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{pplx} %setta il carattere

\usepackage[margin=3.0cm,bindingoffset=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace} %setta l'interlinea a 1,5
\onehalfspacing

\usepackage{graphicx} %pacchetto immagini
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{eulervm} %paccchetto testo formule

%-------------------------------
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\newcommand{\changefont}{%
    \fontsize{10}{11}\selectfont
}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\changefont \slshape \leftmark}
\fancyfoot[C]{\changefont \thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
%-------------------------------

%------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\blankpage}{\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage} %comando pagina vuota
%------------------------------------------------------------------    


\begin{document}

    \frontmatter
    \input{parti/frontmatter/frontespizio}
    \blankpage
    \input{parti/frontmatter/dedica}
    \blankpage
    \input{parti/frontmatter/abstract}
    \blankpage
    \input{parti/frontmatter/ringraziamenti}
    \blankpage

    \renewcommand\contentsname{Indice}
    \tableofcontents
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Indice}
    \renewcommand\listfigurename{Lista delle Figure}
    \listoffigures
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Lista delle Figure}
    \renewcommand\listtablename{Lista delle Tabelle}
    \listoftables
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Lista delle Tabelle}

    \mainmatter
    \input{parti/mainmatter/chapter_1}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I would the next page cleared. What I don't want is the heading. How can I remove it in the second page?

Comment: Please provide a complete MWE with details.

Comment: What I mean is to remove pagestyle in the second page of tableofcontents. I don't know how to provide a MWE

Comment: @HarishKumar I posted an image t0 show you what I mean. as you can see, the second page have the head.how can i remove it?

Comment: @Mazzy, please, try my answer below. Copy and paste the code in the preamble.

Comment: posted all my code

Comment: Don't use the openright option.

Comment: @HarishKumar: `\cleardoublepage` is not issued *after* `\tableofcontents` but (in this case) by `\listoffigures`. Your `{\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage \tableofcontents}` will not suppress pages after the table of contents, only empty pages before.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to remove header/footer on blank pages.

```
\makeatletter
\def\cleardoublepage{%
   \clearpage
   \if@twoside \ifodd\c@page
                  \else \null
                \thispagestyle{empty}
                \newpage
               \fi
   \fi
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: I bet that `\usepackage{emptypage}` is easier. `:-)`

Comment: I had never heard about this package before. Nice!!

Comment: The KOMA-classes (e.g. scrbook) offer commands and options to set the page style of this pages. The default is `cleardoublepage=empty`.