# command to create empty pages for all blank pages

Tags: header-footer

Is there a simple command one can put in the preamble to treat all blank pages like empty pages (with no page number and no header)?

Comment: Are you looking for something like [how-to-remove-headers-and-footers-for-pages-between-chapters](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1681/how-to-remove-headers-and-footers-for-pages-between-chapters)

Comment: yes, this is exactly what I need, thanks a lot.

Comment: Try `\usepackage{emptypage}`

Comment: \usepackage{emptypage} does not work for me. It's a double sided book.